# No se ha dado ningun argumento que corresponda al parametro formal requerido

Tags: c#, mysql

Tengo un sistema de login que identifica administrador y usuario, cuando es administrador muestra las opciones de agregar un usuario o eliminarlo, pero no puedo insertar por que me sale ése error.

Ésta es la clase conexión:

```
namespace Login
{
   public class conexion
    {
        public static void logear(string usuario, string contrasena)
        {

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=seguridad;Uid=root;pwd=;port=3306");

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT tipo_usuario FROM login WHERE usuario='" + usuario + "' and contra='" + contrasena + "'", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("usuario", usuario);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pas", contrasena);
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
                {

                    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "admin")
                    {
                        Administrador fr = new Administrador();
                        fr.Show();
                    }
                    else if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "usuario")
                    {
                        Usuario use = new Usuario();
                        use.Show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("credenciales incorrectas");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ésta es la clase para insertar funciones como insertar e eliminar :

```
public class Funciones
{
    public static int agregar(DatosBD add)
    {
        int retorno = 0;

        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("insert into login values('{0}','{1}','{2}')", add.usuario, add.contra, add.tipo_usuario),conexion.logear());

        retorno = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return retorno;

    }
}
```

En la parte de `conexion.logear()` es donde me marca el error

> No se ha dado ningun argumento que corresponda al parametro formal
>   requerido'usuario' de conexion.logear(string,string)

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tienes es que tu función `logear` te pide 2 argumentos (`string usuario, string contrasena`) que no estás pasando cuando la llamas en `conexion.logear()`.

Deberías añadir esos parámetros cuando llamas la función de la siguiente forma:

```
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("insert into login values('{0}','{1}','{2}')", 
    add.usuario, add.contra, add.tipo_usuario), conexion.logear("EL_USUARIO", "LA_CONTRASEÑA"));
```

Comment: me tira un error que dice que usuario y contrasena no existen en el contexto actual :/

Comment: @FernandoContreras Tienes que poner tu usuario y tu contraseña del SQL, no `"EL_USUARIO", "LA_CONTRASEÑA"` (esto lo he puesto para que sepas que ahi va tu usuario y tu contraseña)